# tested vs be tested

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, grammaticality-in-context

Why do we say "Ten people tested positive today"?

Shouldn’t it be "Ten people were tested positive today" as the lab technicians are testing the samples?

Comment: The verb "test" can be used in the both forms of  transitive and intransitive.

Comment: This is actually an excellent question. (1) ✔ Ten people tested today. (2) ✔ Ten people tested positive today. (3) ✔ Ten people were tested today. (4) ✘ Ten people were tested positive today. (5) ✔ Ten people will test tomorrow. (6) ✔ Ten people will test positive tomorrow. On the face of it, there is no reason why (4) should be wrong. It follows from all of the other tenses and constructions that it should be fine. But it isn't. I suspect this has something to do with simple idiomatic usage where, against logic, we just don't use that specific tense and construction.

Answer (score 1):

“Test” can be transitive or intransitive.

“Test” as an intransitive verb means “get a result in a test.”

“Ten people tested positive today.” = “Ten people received the result of Positive (as opposed to the result of Negative) in their clinical tests.” In short, it focuses not on tests but on test results.

On the other hand, “test” as a transitive verb means “put to test“ or “subject to test.” It refers to the testing of people and has nothing to do with the test results

“Ten people were tested today.” = “Ten people were put to (clinical) test today.”

But your second example (“ Ten people were tested positive today.”) is not only confusing but incorrect as well. It combines the transitive use (in passive voice) with the meaning of the intransitive verb.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the use of the passive voice for the second sentence reduces clarity slightly and takes emphasis off of the subject of the sentence. If someone says

> Ten people tested positive today.

The emphasis is on the subject since the sentence is in the active voice. If someone says

> Ten people were tested positive today.

The use of the passive voice has the effect of [placing emphasis on the action](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/academic_writing/active_and_passive_voice/choosing_passive_voice.html) of testing (since the sentence agent is missing), which may be more desirable in scientific or clinical writing to create the appearance of [an objective, fact-based discourse](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/academic_writing/active_and_passive_voice/more_about_passive_voice.html).

I believe that sentences like "Ten people tested positive today." are more common in everyday speech because speakers wish to place emphasis on the people who were tested positive, not on the action of testing or the unspoken agent of the testing (the laboratory technicians). As Jason Bassford suggested, this has probably has more to do with the nuances of idiomatic usage rather than formal grammar rules.

Answer (score 0):

> Ten people tested positive.

This is a someone uncommon and grammatically weird usage of “to test”:

intransitive verb
1b: **to be assigned** a standing or evaluation on the basis of tests

“Ten people” is the subject, and “positive” is an adjective complement describing the result. Notice that the definition makes it passive even in what appears to be the active form. Someone else (not stated) performed the test on the subject.

> Ten people were tested positive today.

This is the more common and grammatically straightforward meaning of “to test”:

transitive verb
1: to put to test or proof

“Ten people” would be the *object* in active form, which becomes the subject in passive form. But either way, it can’t accept the adjective complement “positive”.

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford English Dictionary says this is an intransitive use of "test" with a phrasal complement.

Similarly, Lexico defines it as follows (sense 1.5): "*no object, with complement* Produce a specified result in a medical test, especially a drugs test or AIDS test.
*‘he tested positive for steroids during the race’"*.

Given that this is an intransitive use, it is unsurprising that the passive use "was tested positive" is much less common.  Indeed, in NGrams, "he tested positive" is around 98% (and was originally 100%) of the combined total of "he tested positive+he was tested positive+he is tested positive" ([source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20tested%20positive%2F%28he%20tested%20positive%2Bhe%20was%20tested%20positive%2Bhe%20is%20tested%20positive%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#)).